# Meme Type Error on UiWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a iOS app which has a uiwebview where it opens a website, but any link clicked in the webview opens up in Safari. In my code bellow, it get a memetype error on the line "webView.load(request)". Can you give me some code so I can fix this? Thanks! (I need to use a UIWebView instead of a WKWebView)

```
class VideosViewController : UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView : UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com") else { return }

    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)

}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == .linkClicked {

        guard let url = request.url else { return true }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you have the error?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say (lol) on the line "webView.load(request)"

Answer (score 0):

Try  to call `webView.loadRequest(request)`. This function has only one `URLRequest` parameter.

Comment: It takes away the error, but the links clicked open in the webview instead of the Safari app. Can you help me with this, or do you see any error in the code??

Comment: If you want to open link is Safari, you don't need `UIWebView`. Just call `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` in needed function

Comment: I want a website to load in the uiwebview, but I want any links clicked INSIDE the webview to open in the Safari app.

Comment: I see. Check `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. It calls every time you click link inside `UIWebView`

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new at coding, and still learning. I don't exactly know what that means. :)

Comment: Add your `VideosViewController` as delegate of `UIWebView` and add method above. With this method you can check all link clicks.

Comment: Did you set delegate for `UIWebView`?

Comment: Oh, wait. I need to webView.delegate = self